# Why does certain query fails?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to run following query with knex.js:

```
database.raw(
    'SELECT DISTINCT ON(tiger_id) tiger_id, created_at, latitude, longitude, id' +
    'FROM images ' +
    'ORDER BY tiger_id, created_at DESC;'
)
```

Any other query goes well, but this one fails with following error:

```
error: column "tiger_id" does not exist
at Connection.parseE (/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Table `tigers` (as you can see, `tiger_id` column exists here):[image: tigers table]

Results of same query made with pgAdmin (the same I expect knex query to return): [image: query result]

So what is the problem here? Is there any other way to get expected result?

Comment: might be a race effect, maybe you need to ``await`` certain functions before executing your query?

Comment: @HRK44 there is only one query running at the same time. Also there were no problems with other queries before, as I mentioned already

Comment: How was the table created?

Comment: @RaymondNijland with knex migration. Should I post it there?

Comment: Does it work when you do `SELECT DISTINCT ON("tiger_id")` ?

Comment: "Try to wrap column names with backtick and remove the plusses and extra apostrophs" backticks is MySQL only syntax @Refilon

Comment: @RaymondNijland "tiger_id" doesn't help

Comment: "with knex migration. Should I post it there?" Don't have anny knowledge of knex so that will not help

Comment: Does this query work? `SELECT * FROM images`  otherwise try `SELECT * FROM public.images` or `SELECT * FROM "images"`.. PostgreSQL can sometimes be trickly selecting the table depening how the table is created.

Comment: @RaymondNijland okay, I found what the problem was. I was just stupid enough to lose space at the end of the first line. Sorry for bothering you

Comment: Ok np.. Then iam close closing the question that it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error

Comment: In general, it's always good to print the generated query to check for any syntax issues.

Comment: "it's always good to print the generated query to check for any syntax issues." indeed but the error generated by knex looks like to be very misleading.. @HRK44 .. i would expected a general PostgreSQL syntax error.

Comment: @RaymondNijland so should I post about this problem somewhere in knex community?

Comment: "so should I post about this problem somewhere in knex community" That might be a good idea because this looks to be a buggy syntax error reporting.

Comment: @NikitaPopov it doesn't seem like a knex issue, you are concatenating strings to form a query, if you concatenate wrongly, the query won't execute and might report strange errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was me skipped space in the end of the first line, so the working query is:

```
database.raw(
    'SELECT DISTINCT ON(tiger_id) tiger_id, created_at, latitude, longitude, id ' +
    'FROM images ' +                                               // this one ^
    'ORDER BY tiger_id, created_at DESC;'
)
```